# Groovy @Grab generating java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, jsoup, gaelyk

I am attempting to get Jsoup to work on my Google App Engine experiment project with Gaelyk.  I work with Grails at my day job, so figured it would be a piece of cake to start playing with Gaelyk...  Not so fast...

The error happens when I include:

```
@Grab('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2')
```

Project builds. But, accessing the page where I am doing the HTML scraping I get this error:

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing `/.`
>
> ```
> Reason: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExeption:  org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
> ```

Not having much luck updating the `build.gradle` file I use with Glide to build the project....  Any ideas would be MOST appreciated!

Comment: I don't think @Grab is compatible with App Engine as it does some naughty ClassLoader magic. adding the dependency to build.gradle file is the way to go. can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: I agree on @Grab.  I removed it like the answer below suggested!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using glide, put this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.appspot.glide-gae" version "0.9.3"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2" 
}
```

In your Groovlet, all you need is:

```
import org.jsoup.*

def doc = Jsoup.connect("http://<your-url-here>").get()
```

And you are back in business

Update: I have added a sample [Scraper](https://github.com/kdabir/glide/tree/master/samples/scraper) in glide-samples

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick.  I removed the @Grab and updated build.gradle and it worked!  I had stared at this so long it drove me nuts!